# php artisan migrate:reset failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel

when I ran

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

I got

```
[ErrorException]
include(app/database/migrations/2014_08_06_120900_alter_xxx_table.php): failed to
open stream: No such file or directory
```

But I don't have that php file, I just have another file named

```
2014_08_06_121048_alter_xxx_table.php
```

And the `migrations` table in mysql has only

```
2014_08_06_121048_alter_xxx_table.php
```

but not

```
2014_08_06_120900_alter_xxx_table.php
```

Now I can't reset my database. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

First:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then make de rollback.

This work for me...

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

solve the same problem of mine.. rather than change manually

Comment: I was using artisan migrate::refresh to update my dev db, got the error message "php artisan migrate:reset failed to open stream: No such file or directory," Googled that error message to find the fix, this SO post was the top match, and this was the answer that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Deleting the row with 2014_08_06_121048_alter_xxx_table in table `migrations` didn't really solve the problem. When I run `php artisan migrate:reset` again, the problem comes again too.

Finally I find the essential reason myself. Due to some reason maybe some wrong commands, wrong filename had been written into

```
./vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

So I correct the filename in this file, everything works well now.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you did a migration, then later on deleted a migration file *before* you did the rollback. So now Laravel is not sure *how* to rollback your database.

Easiest solution (since you are reseting anyway) is to manually clear all the tables from your database, including the migration table.

Then just run `php artisan migrate` and it will install the table and run your migrations.

In the future you should not manually alter your migration files unless you have rollbacked first.

Comment: `php artisan migrate` returns `Nothing to migrate.`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to do that. I'll try later

Comment: `php artisan migrate`
`  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name ....`

Comment: ...so if the column *already exists* you either did not correctly clear the database like I said OR you have two migration functions that are doing the same thing on a table and trying to create the same column

Comment: I recovered the `migrations` table, after that I deleted the last row with `2014_08_06_121048_alter_xxx_table`. Then `php artisan migrate:reset` works fine. Thanks!

Comment: you can delete the last row, if you have deleted the migration file.. then migration can be rolled back

Answer (score 1):

This command works

```
php artisan optimize 
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Answer (score 1):

Undo the actions the migration done on the database. Then look at the migrations table and remove the row relating to the file you deleted.

After that you might then need to run

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the file `autoload_classmap.php` in `/vendor/composer`.
Open the file and edit the following:

In `return array{ }` remove the existing `table.php` files.

Example:

`'CreatePasswordResetsTable'` => `$baseDir . '/database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php'`,

`'CreateUsersTable'` => `$baseDir . '/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php'`,

I removed the above two lines from that array and again executed `php artisan make:User -m` and it created model as well as migration.

Answer (score 0):

This same issue occurred to me while creating a sessions table. Basically  it cannot find the path app/database/migrations/2014_08_06_120900_alter_xxx_table.php.
One possibility is that your database/migrations path  is not app/database/migrations. So first you should find your correct path for database/migrations. I was using a october cms framework on top of it and found my path was "modules/system/database/migrations".
You need to open the `SessionTableCommand.php` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Console path`. On the line #77 you will find $path variable. Change that to your path for database/migrations. 
In my case line 77 looked like this:

```
$path = 'modules/system/database/migrations';
```

These errors happen mostly because of incorrect path for the file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command. It worked for me.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

It do well in windows10.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should manually create folder migrations. Then composer update. And run migrations