# Windows 10 Laravel project not running migrations failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I've cloned a Laravel 5.4 project created on a Mac to my Windows 10.
Then, I've did a composer update.

When I try to do php artisan migrate, I get this error:

In ClassLoader.php line 444:

include(C:\Users\José Dalri\Workspace\Projetos\laravel-5.4\vendor\composer/../../atabase/migrations/2017_08_29_122558_create_activity_log_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I've tryed the suggestions here: [php artisan migrate:reset failed to open stream: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237415/php-artisan-migratereset-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)
but not happened.

I've created a new Laravel 5.5 project on my Windows and than the migrations worked fine.

Any help?

Comment: Did you try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Yes I did, but the same problem happened